# Is it possible to attach xsd to xml, if xsd locate in the internet, Not on this pc?

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xsd

```
<product name="qwerty" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceLocation="product.xsd">
```

Can i change product.xsd on some URL of xsd file, something like that:

```
<product name="qwerty" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceLocation="http://www.example.com/product.xsd">
```

Comment: According to this article it should work fine: https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/learn-xml-schema/namespaces.cfm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Intellij-IDEA I try to do so:

```
<product name="qwerty" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceLocation="http://www.example.com/product.xsd">
```

And location of my xsd become red. I tap alt+enter and it is fix my problem. Also IDEA add in "File, Settings, Schemas & DTDs" my URL.